# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object on server. The object is associated with property File" when read file from SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I've read file from url sharepoint and it returns that error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object on server. The
> object is associated with property File

I've tried to count number of file in this folder url so it could count true, but when I printing the file name, it had error at line `this.lblMessage.Text = listItems.First().File.Name.ToString();`

This is my code:

```
var targetSiteURL = new Uri("https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/test");
ClientContext cxt = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
cxt.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
                    
var list = cxt.Web.GetList("/sites/test/Shared%20Documents");

var listItems = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
cxt.Load(listItems,
items => items.Include(
item => item.File));
cxt.ExecuteQuery();                    
this.lblMessage.Text = listItems.First().File.Name.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Caml Query to filter only files in the library as item.File.Name is used for File not Folder:

```
                var list = cxt.Web.GetList("/sites/test/Shared%20Documents");
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml =
                   @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>  
                    <Query> 
                       <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq></Where> 
                    </Query> 
                    </View>";
                var listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                cxt.Load(listItems,items => items.Include(item => item.File));
                cxt.ExecuteQuery();
               Console.WriteLine(listItems.First().File.Name);
```

Comment: I found that problem and fixed it done this morning. Thank you for spending time to review my problem. Many thanks.